# Map files function paths

Tags: c

Is there any way to get the absolute path of functions in map files? Map files support following format

```
0001:000016a0       func                   00000001400026a0 f   lib:func.o
```

Is there any way to get the absolute path of "func"

Answer (score 0):

This may not be useful depending on your situation, but some linkers do not support having multiple object files with the same name in different directories.  So if you give them some_directory/func.o and some_other_directory/func.o, only one of them will be linked.  I know CodeWarrior does this.

In order to avoid this problem, I make sure that all of my object files have unique names.  The convention I use is to include an abbreviation of the module name, for example, func_module.o.  With that convention it is easy to identify the object file.  Or if you need to do so programatically, any file searching technique will suffice.

Some versions of Visual Studio put all object files into a single directory, regardless of the organization of the .c and/or .cpp files, and will automatically append numeric suffixes to avoid conflicts.  Figuring out which object file goes to which .c file requires reading the project file.

Comment: I think you are right. Map file gets its data from obj files and which are generally stored in some common directory. So I may not be able to get absolute files paths of c files.